XGBoost - order of columns seen by a tree with `colsample_bytree`<1
My understanding is that XGBoost chooses the first column if two or more columns provide the same gain on a split.
In order to ensure that XGBoost has a chance to look at and include all relevant columns I thought that I can simply pass colsample_bytree=0.99. However, in order for this to work the columns returned by sampling have to be in random order. Is this methodology correct or should I shuffle the columns in some kind of cross validation scheme?

I think you'll find better answers on Stack Overflow. Try starting here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=colsample_bytree

"if two or more columns provide the same gain on a split." This is a somewhat unlikely scenario when working with real data but if the gain is indeed equal, why does it matter which comes first? Maybe it causes a minor distortion to feature importance metrics if we have a small number of iterations, but practically it won't. In any case, features' order are shuffled when sampled so we don't have to worry about it, see https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/f06dcf8be2511d99068b0f353ad3e9ff6641b5ef/src/common/random.cc#L51.

As explained at https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html for colsample_bytree=, subsampling occurs once for every tree constructed. For each tree, the columns to consider are randomly selected. Therefore, the columns do not need to be shuffled manually. All columns have chances to enter some trees even if colsample_bytree= is set to a low proportion.

I think the OP is asking about the case that all columns are selected. (i.e. colsample_bytree= is set to a high proportion)
